# My newgame-button and exitgame-button aren't working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just started java-programming and made a game which was fully working.  The only problems I had were that I couldn't start a new game and that I couldn't exit the app.
So I made 2 buttons.  One should start a new game, and one should exit the game. But when I try to test the buttons, I can only see and click them but nothing happens. Does it have something to do with appcompat_v7? I don't know, I hope you guys knows what's wrong with my code.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.wouter.testjk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.wouter.testjk.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;



        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }



        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            switch (view.getId())
            {
            case R.id.ten:

                startNewGame();
                return;

            case R.id.eleven:

                MainActivity.this.finish();
                return;

            }


            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    setMove(mGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                        setMove(mGame.ANDROID_PLAYER, move);
                        winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    }
                    if (winner == 0)
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                    else if (winner == 1)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }       
                    else if (winner ==2)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                        mHumanCounter++;
                        mHumanCount.setText(Integer.toString(mHumanCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner ==3)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                        mAndroidCounter++;
                        mAndroidCount.setText(Integer.toString(mAndroidCounter));
                        mGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ten"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ten" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eleven"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:text="@string/eleven" />
</TableRow>
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="ten">new game</string>
<string name="eleven">exit game</string>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast your class to an OnClickListener as it should implement it. Not that that would/should fix the problem, just helps reduce unnecessary casting. Is it possible something else is pulling focus? What other views/listeners are you using (if any)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought it looked very stange indeed. I will update the code, and add other listeners

Comment: I added the other listener in the code, isnt it possible to have 2 listerners in 1 class?

Comment: I want to add a comment cause it doesn't really need an answer, but it is too long so I will

Comment: Okay thank you, im waiting for your awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't have two onClickListeners at once because Android has no way of distinguishing which to use (and will only trigger one at a time). You can do one of two things.

**1. Instead of setting the click listener for ten and eleven to this, set it to new ButtonClickListener(-1)**

for example `mTen.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(-1));`

This will allow you to perform the functionality in your ButtonClickListener as so

```
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.ten:
        startNewGame();
        return;
    case R.id.eleven:
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        return;
}

if(!mGameOver){
    // The rest of your ButtonClickListener click logic as you have it now
```

**2. Get rid of the ButtonClickListener class**

This can be done by adding a tag to your button that represents its location for the buttons that aren't ten and eleven. Something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.size(); i++){
     mBoardButtons[i].setTag(i);
     mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

You would then use the same code as if you were using option 1, but instead of putting it in ButtonClickListener's onClick method, you would put it in your Activity's onClick() method. Then, instead of using `location` as your variable, use `(int) view.getTag()`.

I can go into more detail or provide more code if you need me to, but this should give you a start.

Comment: Thank you, I appriciate you for helping me. I am going to try this, if I wont succeed I will come back

Comment: Finally I can this this, because I had some errors before I could... But it still doenst work somehow, I tried the first method, I will update that class in my post above

Comment: @goedkoop sorry it took me a while to get back, look at the line underneath option 1. You are forgetting to change the onClickListener() type.

Comment: Ow sorry, I forgot to set ur awnser as marked. I fixed it, thanks for all the help mate!